# How to insert string variable into this long python SQL string?

Tags: python, mysql, string

I have a MySQL query that is stored in a python string. It looks like this;

```
query = """ SELECT colA, colB
            FROM table WHERE colC = '1' """
```

Suppose I want to insert string variable to construct the same `query`.

Can I do something similar to this?

```
Var1 = 'colA'
Var2 = 'colB'
query = """ SELECT %s, %s
                FROM table WHERE colC = '1' """, Var1, Var2
```

How can I do this in python? I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Can someone explain why the negative vote? I believe it is a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use column names as SQL parameters; you'll have to manually interpolate the name; you could use [`str.format()` string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for this:

```
query = """ SELECT `{}`, colB
            FROM table WHERE colC = '1' """.format(Var1)
```

The `` ` `` backticks around the `{}` placeholder serve to make sure your column identifier is interpreted as such even if it contains whitespace or a name that is a keyword otherwise.

Multiple columns take multiple placeholders:

```
query = """ SELECT `{}`, `{}`
            FROM table WHERE colC = '1' """.format(Var1, Var2)
```

Be *extremely careful* when doing this and always pre-validate that `Var1` is a valid column name. Don't blindly accept user input as you will not be protected from SQL injection attacks otherwise.

Comment: What if I have 2 variables - `Var1` and `Var2`. Say `Var2 = colB`. How will the code looks like? I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @user3293156: use multiple `{}` placeholders, and pass multiple arguments to the `str.format()` method: `"""SELECT \`{}\`, \`{}\` FROM ...""".format(Var1, Var2)`.

Comment: Thank you. You are most helpful.